# How do I pass a C++11 random number generator to a function?

Tags: c++, random, c++11

Do they all inherit from a base class?  Do I have to use templates?

(I am referring to these http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c15319/)

I am doing this right now:

```
typedef std::mt19937 RNG;
```

and then

```
class Chooser {
public:
    Chooser(RNG& rng, uint n, uint min_choices, uint max_choices):
```

In other words, I'm passing references to RNG.  How would I pass in an arbitrary generator?

Also, I realize this is maybe a different question, but how do I pass the generator to STL?

```
std::random_shuffle(choices_.begin(), choices_.end(), rng);
```

doesn't seem to work.

---

solution to passing generator:

```
typedef std::ranlux64_base_01 RNG;
typedef std::mt19937 RNGInt;
```

solution to passing to STL:

```
struct STL_RNG {
    STL_RNG(RNGInt& rng): gen(rng) {}       
    RNGInt& gen;
    int operator()(int n) { return std::uniform_int<int>(0, n)(gen); }
};
```

Comment: According to that article, they are already functors so you should be ready to go. What's the problem?

Comment: We'd probably be able to give more specific and helpful information if we knew your goal.

Comment: Specifically, how do you want your generators to be different, and what's the compiler error you get for `random_shuffle`?

Comment: A functor is an object, but his `RNG` is a type. `RNG()` would be a (temporary) functor.

Comment: Using your ideas, I put together a simple solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They don't all inherit from a base (which is a little surprising), but it doesn't matter because that's not how C++ functors work.

For arbitrary RNGs of a single given type, you got it right as (now) posted.

If you mean, how do I *define* a function which accepts any random number generator as an argument.

```
template< class RNG > // RNG may be a functor object of any type
int random_even_number( RNG &gen ) {
    return (int) gen() * 2;
}
```

You don't need to use any more templates than this, because of type deduction.

---

Defining one function to accept different RNG's is trickier because semantically that requires having a common base type. You need to define a base type.

```
struct RNGBase {
    virtual int operator() = 0;
    virtual ~RNGBase() {};
};

template< class RNG >
struct SmartRNG : RNGBase {
    RNG gen;

    virtual int operator() {
        return gen();
    }
};

int random_even_number( RNGBase &gen ) { // no template
    return (int) gen() * 2; // virtual dispatch
}
```

Comment: that's really unfortunate, because it means that I have to have all of my random functions in headers.

Comment: @Neil: See my second answer (I only committed the first paragraph at first). I think the intent of the standard is that you pick one generator and stick to it. There is no need for any of this if you only want to use `std::mt19937`… but that's unclear from your question.

Comment: You're right.  Thanks for the rest of your answer.  I am happy limiting myself to mt if it makes the code easier to deal with.

Comment: If you're going to give answers about modern C++, maybe not use `(int)` as a casting syntax?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout sir, this post is 12 years old

Comment: I noticed that. But since it still showed up on the front page, maybe you can do a small edit? People do consult old answers. And C++11 is still the basis of modern C++, so your answer is actually still relevant.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me was using an `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <random>

void exampleFunction(std::function<int()> rnd) {
    auto randomNumber = rnd();
}

std::minstd_rand rnd;
exampleFunction([&rnd](){ return rnd(); });

// This won't work as it passes a copy of the object, so you end up with the same
// sequence of numbers on every call.
exampleFunction(rnd);
```

You're not really passing around the random object, just a method to call the object's `operator ()`, but it achieves the same effect.

Note that here the precision of the random number generator's return value may be reduced as the `std::function` is declared as returning an `int`, so you may want to use a different data type instead of `int` depending on your need for precision.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a class or functor that fit your needs?

Comment: Is there an automated way to wrap something like that in a functor?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two methods:  Function Objects and Function Pointers.  In either case, enable your class to receive a Function Object or a Function Pointer to the random number generator.

With a Function Object, you can define a base class, and have your receiving class implement functions that require a pointer to the base function object class.  This gives you more freedom in defining many different function objects without changing the interface of the receiving class.