# Sharing a random engine in multiple functions

Tags: c++, random

so my question in a nutshell would be: How do I access a random engine initialized in `main()` from another function without passing the engine as an argument?

I read that is a good habit to initialize a random engine only once in a program.
I would do it like this at the beginning of my `main()` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::default_random_engine; 
using std::uniform_int_distribution;

int main() {
  int seed = time(0);
  default_random_engine engine(seed);              
  uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,100); 
  cout << "Random num: " << engine(dist) << endl;
}
```

But how would I make it accessible to other functions? E.g., in a nested structure where function `func_a` calls `func_b`, which is supposed to do something with a random number generated by the engine.
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::default_random_engine; 
using std::uniform_int_distribution;

void func_b() {
  // do sth
  cout << "Print a random number: " << endl;
}

void func_a() {
  func_b();
}

int main() {
  int seed = time(0);
  default_random_engine engine(seed);              
  uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,100); 
  func_a();
}
```

### **EDIT: Problem Solved, thanks.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>


using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::default_random_engine; 
using std::uniform_int_distribution;

////////////////////////
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
////////////////////////

int seed = time(0);
default_random_engine engine(seed);

////////////////////////
// FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
////////////////////////

void func_b() {
  uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,100);
  cout << dist(engine) << endl;
}

void func_a() {
  func_b();
}

int main() {
  int seed = time(0);
  default_random_engine engine(seed);              
  uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,100); 
  func_a();
}
```

Comment: Either you pass it around via as a reference argument, or you make it a global, or you make it a `static` variable inside a globally accessible function, which returns it by reference. Personally, I wouldn't find so tragic to make it a global.

Comment: If you pass it as an argument, you can test each function individually.

Comment: Yes, why not making it global...I think I will just go with that. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, making it global didn't work so well, I added an example code and an error message I am getting. Hope someone can help me figuring out what is going on there. Thanks!

Comment: Btw. Why do you use `time`, when `std::random_device` is available?

Comment: `dist(engine)`, not `engine(dist)`. And either `using std::endl;` or `<< std::endl`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess today is not my day...

Comment: Please move your solution into the answer section below, which you can then mark as accepted taking your question off the unanswered list.

Comment: Have a look at "[How do I pass a C++11 random number generator to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241327/how-do-i-pass-a-c11-random-number-generator-to-a-function)" for a solution without global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. I copy the solution to the answer section so it can be marked as accepted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>


using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::default_random_engine; 
using std::uniform_int_distribution;

////////////////////////
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
////////////////////////

int seed = time(0);
default_random_engine engine(seed);

////////////////////////
// FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
////////////////////////

void func_b() {
  uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,100);
  cout << dist(engine) << endl;
}

void func_a() {
  func_b();
}

int main() {
  int seed = time(0);
  default_random_engine engine(seed);              
  uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,100); 
  func_a();
}
```